# How do I convert "8.1076e-05" into 0.0000811 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

In my array of strings, I have some values like "8.1076e-05". The problem I encountered while shorting. I used the code `FinalHierarchy = sortrows(B, 3, 'descend');` to short, the result is below.

```
   "FC624  "    "0.010686"     "9.5329e-05"
"FC642  "    "0.0044959"    "8.2636e-05"
"FC621  "    "0.0090886"    "8.1076e-05"
"FC622  "    "0.0086253"    "7.6943e-05"
"FC623  "    "0.0080882"    "7.2152e-05"
"FC643  "    "0.0028437"    "5.2267e-05"
"FC646  "    "0.0025469"    "4.6813e-05"
"FC644  "    "0.0012072"    "2.2189e-05"
"FC122  "    "0.0073847"    "0.00077775"
"FC142  "    "0.010012"     "0.00072479"
"FC131  "    "0.0094101"    "0.00071951"
"FC121  "    "0.0068294"    "0.00071926"
"FC521  "    "0.0095355"    "0.00069401"
"FC112  "    "0.0087711"    "0.00063404"
"FC111  "    "0.008607"     "0.00062218"
"FC531  "    "0.0058125"    "0.00055105"
"FC141  "    "0.0074634"    "0.0005403" 
"FC228  "    "0.0098074"    "0.00049734"
"FC224"      "0.009434"     "0.0004784" 
"FC221  "    "0.0092251"    "0.00046782"
"FC225"      "0.0088874"    "0.00045069"
```

It can be seen above that MATLAB has considered the value `2.2189e-05` bigger than `0.00077775`. I guess the reason behind it is, MATLAB compared `2.2189` with `0.00077775`. It is because the column is a string. In my calculation, `column 2` and `column 3` were double but when I concatenated them with a string `column 1` as  `'B'`, it became string.
I guess it might have a very easy solution if `2.2189e-05` stays as `0.00002219`. I try to change the `format` to `longG` but the problem still persists.
Can someone suggest any idea to deal with it?

Comment: I would advise against concatenating with a string. Instead, put your data in a `table` or even a cell array.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But Cris, can you please explain more the benefits of your suggestion over Matteo solution. It would be really nice to know more methods with pros and cons.

Comment: If you store the values in a cell array or a table, then they’re never converted to a string. You keep the numbers in their natural format. This has many advantages, I’m sure you can imagine. Matteo’s answer relies on recovering the numeric representation from the string, which is expensive and does not necessarily preserve all the digits. The number should not be converted to a string in the first place.

Comment: Got it @CrisLuengo. Thanks for the clear expalination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it is because your elements are strings. So what you could do is:

```
% Sort the column after having casted it to double
[~, idx] = sort(str2double(B(:, 3)), 'descend');

% Apply the sorting to the initial matrix
FinalHierarchy  = B(idx, :);
```